# maximal number of identical elements between any two columns of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I just was wondering if there was an easy way to compute the maximal number of identical elements between any two columns of a matrix in R.

For example, I have a matrix

```
test <- replicate(10, sample((0:3), 10, replace = TRUE))

test

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    3    0    1    0    2    2    1    0    2     0
 [2,]    1    1    3    2    0    2    3    0    2     2
 [3,]    2    3    0    0    1    2    0    3    0     2
 [4,]    2    2    1    1    2    0    0    1    1     0
 [5,]    2    0    1    2    0    1    1    1    0     0
 [6,]    1    0    1    3    2    3    3    1    3     2
 [7,]    0    1    3    2    1    0    1    2    1     1
 [8,]    0    3    1    3    0    2    3    1    1     1
 [9,]    2    3    1    3    0    1    0    1    3     2
[10,]    3    2    1    0    2    1    3    2    3     1
```

To compare column 1 and 2 I use

```
table(test[,1] == test[,2])

FALSE  TRUE 
    8     2
```

So there are two identical elements between these two columns.

I could now repeat this for all pairs of columns using two nested for loops and then find the maximum number of TRUE calls but this does not look nice. Can anyone think of a better way?

Cheers,

Maik

Comment: Try `combn(ncol(test), 2, FUN = function(x) sum(test[, x[1]] == test[, x[2]]))` maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
max(combn(split(test, col(test)), 2, function(x) sum(x[[1]] == x[[2]])))
```

If you want to know which pair has the greatest number of equal elements it's a little more complicated.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Believe it or not I didn't. I saw your comment before posting my answer but I decided to post it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It is always interesting to see a reasonable answer being voted down. Though I don't like this minus score, I would keep my answer. Voter, what do you think?

---

Let's first get some **reproducible** toy data:

```
set.seed(0); x <- replicate(10, sample((0:3), 10, replace = TRUE))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    3    0    3    1    1    2    1    3    3     0
# [2,]    1    0    3    1    3    1    3    1    1     0
# [3,]    1    0    0    2    2    3    1    3    2     0
# [4,]    2    2    2    1    3    1    1    1    1     2
# [5,]    3    1    0    0    2    0    1    1    1     3
# [6,]    0    3    1    3    2    0    2    1    3     3
# [7,]    3    1    1    2    3    0    1    3    0     3
# [8,]    3    2    0    3    0    1    1    3    2     1
# [9,]    2    3    1    0    1    2    3    1    0     1
#[10,]    2    1    3    2    2    2    0    3    0     3
```

For any input matrix `x`, you can use:

```
y <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(ncol(x)-1L),
                   function(i) colSums(x[, (i+1):ncol(x), drop = FALSE] == x[, i])))
# [1] 1 2 3 2 4 1 4 2 3 3 1 0 0 3 1 3 5 1 3 1 2 4 1 4 3 4 2 3 5 1 1 3 2 1 2 2 3 3
#[39] 1 2 3 1 4 3 1
max(y)
# [1] 5
```

**The comment by @David is doing essentially the same thing but way slower**:

```
y <- combn(ncol(x), 2, FUN = function(u) sum(x[, u[1]] == x[, u[2]]))
# [1] 1 2 3 2 4 1 4 2 3 3 1 0 0 3 1 3 5 1 3 1 2 4 1 4 3 4 2 3 5 1 1 3 2 1 2 2 3 3
#[39] 1 2 3 1 4 3 1
max(y)
# [1] 5
```

**Benchmarking**

We generate a 10 * 1000 matrix for experiment:

```
set.seed(0); x <- replicate(1e+3, sample((0:3), 10, replace = TRUE))
system.time(unlist(lapply(seq_len(ncol(x)-1L), function(i) colSums(x[, (i+1):ncol(x), drop = FALSE] == x[, i]))))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.176   0.032   0.207 
system.time(combn(ncol(x), 2, FUN = function(u) sum(x[, u[1]] == x[, u[2]])))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  4.692   0.008   4.708
```

---

**Something like a distance matrix?**

With this idea, you could also generate a "distance" matrix for number of **non-equal** elements between all columns (just replace the `==` with `!=`):

```
y <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(ncol(x)-1L),
                   function(i) colSums(x[, (i+1):ncol(x), drop = FALSE] != x[, i])))
z <- matrix(0L, ncol(x), ncol(x))
z[lower.tri(z)] <- y
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [2,]    9    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [3,]    8    7    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [4,]    7    9    9    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [5,]    8   10    7    7    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [6,]    6   10    9    6    9    0    0    0    0     0
# [7,]    9    7    8    8    7    8    0    0    0     0
# [8,]    6    9    6    7    8    7    8    0    0     0
# [9,]    8    7    9    5    9    7    7    6    0     0
#[10,]    7    5    6    9    8    9    9    7    9     0
```

Note that **only lower triangular matrix is computed due to symmetry**. Diagonal are all zeros (or course).