# Compute Row Differences

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix such as:

```
m <- matrix(data=cbind(rnorm(30, 0), rnorm(30, 2), rnorm(30, 5)), nrow=30, ncol=3)
```

I want an output matrix with differences between every row. The result might look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38941964/4891738) to a similar but not identical [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38941690/4891738), using `lapply` is much much faster than using `combn`.

Here is what you can do with `lapply`:

```
tm <- t(m)  ## transpose for column wise operation (for better caching)
z <- do.call(cbind, lapply(seq_len(ncol(tm)), function (i) tm - tm[, i]))
row_names <- paste(rep(seq_len(nrow(m)), each = nrow(m)),
                   rep(seq_len(nrow(m)), times = nrow(m)), sep = ";")
matrix(z, ncol = ncol(m), byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(row_names, colnames(m)))
```

Consider a 3 * 3 small example:

```
set.seed(0); m <- matrix(rnorm(3 * 3), ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c("x1","x2","x3")))
```

My code gives:

```
#             x1         x2         x3
#1;1  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
#1;2 -1.58918765 -0.8577879  0.6338466
#1;3  0.06684498 -2.8123794  0.9227999
#2;1  1.58918765  0.8577879 -0.6338466
#2;2  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
#2;3  1.65603262 -1.9545915  0.2889533
#3;1 -0.06684498  2.8123794 -0.9227999
#3;2 -1.65603262  1.9545915 -0.2889533
#3;3  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
```

---

Well, perhaps I should include a new benchmark for those eager to see figures.

```
# a data frame with 500 rows
N <- 500; set.seed(0)
m <- matrix(rnorm(N * 3), ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c("x1","x2","x3")))

## my approach
system.time({tm <- t(m);
z <- do.call(cbind, lapply(seq_len(ncol(tm)), function (i) tm - tm[, i]));
row_names <- paste(rep(seq_len(nrow(m)), each = nrow(m)),
                   rep(seq_len(nrow(m)), times = nrow(m)), sep = ";");
matrix(z, ncol = ncol(m), byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(row_names, colnames(m)))})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.320   0.000   0.318 

## akrun's `combn()` method:
system.time(t(combn(nrow(m), 2, FUN = function(i) m[i[1],]- m[i[2],])))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.324   0.000   1.326 

## akrun's `apply()` method:
system.time({d1 <- expand.grid(1:nrow(m), 1:nrow(m));
rn <- do.call(paste, c(d1,  sep=";"));
res <- t(apply(d1, 1, function(i) m[i[1],] - m[i[2],]));
row.names(res) <- rn})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  4.768   0.000   4.777
```

500 rows is not large at all, yet speed differs so much.

**If you want to test, you can verify that the time for akrun's both methods grows quadratically at `O(N^2)`, while my approach grows linearly at `O(N)`. For increasingly larger `N`, the benefit of my approach is ever huger.**

Answer (score 2):

If it is between each combination of rows,

```
t(combn(nrow(m), 2, FUN = function(i) m[i[1],]- m[i[2],]))
```

Or using `expand.grid` to also include the difference of the same rows.

```
 d1 <- expand.grid(1:nrow(m), 1:nrow(m))
 rn <- do.call(paste, c(d1,  sep=";"))
 res <- t(apply(d1, 1, function(i) m[i[1],] - m[i[2],]))
 row.names(res) <- rn
```

#### Update

Here is an efficient way to do this

```
 m1 <- m[rep(1:nrow(m), each = nrow(m)),]
 m2 <- m[rep(1:nrow(m), nrow(m)),]
 m1 - m2
```

#### Benchmarks

```
N <- 500; set.seed(0)
m <- matrix(rnorm(N * 3), ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c("x1","x2","x3")))
```

Comparing with **O(N)** or whatever as described in the other post,

```
system.time({tm <- t(m);
z <- do.call(cbind, lapply(seq_len(ncol(tm)), function (i) tm - tm[, i]));
 row_names <- paste(rep(seq_len(nrow(m)), each = nrow(m)),
                   rep(seq_len(nrow(m)), times = nrow(m)), sep = ";");
 matrix(z, ncol = ncol(m), byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(row_names, colnames(m)))})
 #   user  system elapsed 
 #  0.25    0.02    0.27
```

with the new method

```
system.time({m1 <- m[rep(1:nrow(m), each = nrow(m)),]
  m2 <- m[rep(1:nrow(m), nrow(m)),]
   m1 - m2})
 #  user  system elapsed 
 #  0.02    0.00    0.02
```